# Eject sdcard when playing video on internal storage cause "media server died"

Tags: android, media-player, media, android-videoview

I am developing android applications and firmware for a hardware device, the device have internal storage at /mnt/sdcard. When insert external sdcard, it is mounted at /mnt/sdcard/extsd, and /mnt/sdcard/udisk for external usb disk(thumb drive).

Now the problem is, when I am playing a video on internal storage using "VideoView" and I eject the external sdcard, then there is a popup saying that "Sorry, cannot play video".

I looked at the logcat and found something like this

```
WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioFlinger server died!
WARN/AudioSystem(92): AudioPolicyService server died!
INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.player' died
INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.camera' died
INFO/ServiceManager(53): service 'media.audio_policy' died
WARN/IMediaDeathNotifier(912): media server died
WARN/IMediaDeathNotifier(912): media server died
ERROR/MediaPlayer(912): error (100, 0)
```

I am playing a file on internal storage and why removing sdcard cause error to "media server"? or Will the so call "media server" died when ejecting sdcard and is not related to playing video? or the problem is actually not related to "media server"?

The android version I am working on is 2.3.3

Comment: ok, I discovered something. It is not related to playing video. Simply removing sdcard will cause "media server died", anyone experienced this?